# Google Actions Alpha release in created via REST API doesn't works anymore on device (but works in the simulator)

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

Since a couple of days an Alpha release created via REST API doesn't works on the device (smartphone/Google Nest).
The Alpha release is correctly deployed, and I'm able to test it in the simulator, but doesn't starts on the device.
When I re-create the release using the Actions Console (manually), the Action works again on the devices.

Someone has a similar problem ?

Comment: Is your user account enrolled in the alpha? Or do your devices get the Test Version?

Comment: I have seen similar problems. The developer account appears to work fine. All members of the alpha program don't connect. They describe getting "a beep" and nothing else.

Comment: @NickFelker I set the Alpha tester email with a test Gmail that I always used. I tried also different Gmail, without success.

Comment: @Prisoner same for me.